# Font awesome icons are not displaying react

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome and have imported it in  **index.js**

```
import '././styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css';
```

following in filter component

```
<span onClick={this.togglem.bind(this)}>
   {/*<span className="rTitle">Filters</span>*/}
   <i className="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Here, the icon **fa-filter** is not getting displayed can anyone lemme know whats going wrong

Using double dots its throws this exception:

> You attempted to import
> **../../../styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css** which falls outside of the project **src/** directory. Relative imports outside of
> **src/** are not supported.

structure is

```
  src/filter.js  

  src/styles/fontawesome
```

**version -5.5.0**

i've  imported in filter pointings are all right it show the css styles
when inspected but does not show the icon

Answer (score 1):

Your import looks wrong `import '././styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css';` you're probably looking for `import '../../styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css';` (pay attention to the dots).

If you're using React with JSX (you're most likely doing it) you need to use `className` to define html class attribute:

```
<i className="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Also, the right way to use FontAwesome in React in documented here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: dont work className too class also works n .. doesnt work its points outside src

Comment: Can you share your project structure? The path to your CSS is wrong. Using `class` would work but throw an error in React since `class is a reserved word in ES6+`, so always use `className`.

Comment: classname too doesnt apply FontAwesome. Ihave update my code

Comment: According to your file structure, and assuming your `index.js` file is in the `src` folder too: `import './styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css';`

Comment: ya everything is in src as outside it doesnt support i have edited question

Comment: Yes, but if you write `'./styles/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css';` in your `src/index.js` file it should work since `./` refers to the current directory.

Comment: Also, I assume your `index.js` is importing your `filter.js` right? If not, then you may need to import the CSS in `filter.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183419/discussion-between-tested-and-davo).